# Understanding Deep Neural Network for Youtube Recommendation Paper

Tags: neural-networks

I am trying to understand the paper - [deep neural network for youtube recommendation](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/45530.pdf). They divided their approach into two phases - `candidate generation` and `ranking`.

Candidate generation diagram below:
[image]

I understand that the video embeddings are learned jointly with all other model parameters. That means `embedded video watches` and `embedded search tokens` are trained along with the `candidate generation model`.

If you look at the `softmax` box, they are getting `class probabilities` and `video vectors vj`. This is really confusing. How can you extract two different outputs from `softmax`? Or rather I should say how do you extract `video vectors vj` from this model?

Please suggest.

Comment: My understanding is that the softmax is a humongous multiclass classification that identifies/ranks some video ids. You then go ahead and take the embedding of those videos and use them for NN Search. What I'm confused about is the `user vecotr u`, any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 1):

The video vectors $v_j$ are simply the video embeddings; based on what I see, the input into the softmax for the video indexed $j$ for a particular user $u$ is simply $u \cdot v_j$ over the distribution $V$ of all videos. That is, the final layer is performing the operation 
$$\text{softmax}(\mathbf{v}_U); \quad\mathbf{v}_U = [u^\top v_0, u^\top v_1, \dots u^\top v_{|V|}]$$

So similarly to classifiers based on embedding methods, I'm making an educated guess that at some point, you will need to make that explicit $u \cdot v_j$ computation during the forward pass, so at that point, you should be able to get $v_j$ explicitly.